# Как показать прогресс в AsyncTask [Android]?

Tags: android, java, android-asynctask

Есть довольно трудоемкий процесс, который у меня выполняется в AsyncTask, в процессе его выполнения я вывожу ProgressDialog c вращающимся прогресс баром, но теперь мне необходимо внедрить плоский ProgressBar, который в процентах будет показывать процесс выполнения задачи! 
Гуглил ничго не нашел, поэтому обращаюсь к Вам!

Зранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Вывести проценты не сложно. Нужно в методе *progressUpdate* обновлять *progressBar*:

```
@Override  
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values)  
{  
    progressBar.setProgress(values[0]);  
}
```

Главный вопрос, что за задача и можно ли разбить её на части?
Например, если у вас побитное копирование файла, то обновляем progressBar каждые N/100 бит. Где N - размер файла.

Comment: У меня скачивание картинок с сети, при этом extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>, и у меня выдает ошибку! Как публиковать прогресс не понимаю, то что Вы предлагаете пробовал, но не получается!

Answer (score 1):

Ладно, пускай гуглить вы не умеете, а в документация то что вам помешало заглянуть?

Даю опорные точки:

- Выставляем нужный стиль для `ProgressDialog`:

  ```
  progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
  ```
- В нужном месте в `AsyncTask` вызываем `publishProgress(…)` для обновления прогресса `ProgressDialog`'а.
- Переопределяем метод `onProgressUpdate` в `AsyncTask`, в котором, собственно, и выполняем обновление диалога, посредством вызова метода `setProgress`.

Полагаю, всё должно быть вполне понятно.

Comment: Я так и делал, но не получается! Вы не могли бы показать на примере?

Comment: Покажите, что вы сделали.

Comment: У меня он пишет 0% постоянно! Я не понимаю как он вычисляет процент, если он заранее не знает кол-во изображений?

Comment: Проценты вы должны сами вычислить в *doInBackground*, если это возможно, и там же вызвать *publishProgress(процент)*.

Comment: Попробуйте простой пример вроде [этого] [1]

  [1]:http://devcolibri.com/1785

Comment: @ilyarasputin, вы вообще читали, что я написал в ответе выше?

Comment: Нет ни черта! Все одно - 0%!

Comment: @ilyarasputin, код покажите.

Comment: Модифицировать счётчик цикла внутри цикла — плохая идея. И убедитесь, что `ja.length()` > 1. А также, не забывайте делать `progressDialog.setMax(…)`.

Comment: Поставил setMax, вывел count в Log. Он растет, а процент в диалоге как был 0, так 0 и стоит!